# Android RelativeLayout AlignBottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have some trouble with a TextView in on of my XML-files, and I hope one of you can help me.

I dont think it is that hard, but i just cant get it right.

All i want is my "@+id/footer" TextView to fill out the space all the way down to my "@+id/btn_BrowserLink" Button, and keep the TextView inside my ScrollView. And finally it should have a 5dp margin to the Button. Can someone please help meP

Thanks

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background1"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/relativeLayout2"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg2" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textColor="#E97305"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#CCE97305" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"      
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/detail"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg2" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="@string/ticket"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#CCE97305" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the footer view above the Button, but you will have to define the button first (put it closer to the top of the xml file than the text view).

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_below="@id/title"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="#CCE97305" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff" />



<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:text="@string/ticket"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:background="#CCE97305" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff" 
/>


<ScrollView
android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
android:layout_above="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"      
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:scrollbars="none"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textSize="13sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg2" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry it is my footer i want to go down, and it is that view which i need to be inside a scrollview. I will try you answer, but with the footer and not the detail.

Comment: I updated a fuller example. In your scroll view, you should change layout_height to fill_parent so that it takes up all the space

Comment: Okay. Now it fills out the whole space when the textview is parsing alot of text. Is it possible to make the textview/scrollview fill out the whole space all the time?

Comment: change layout_height to fill_parent for the TextView as well

Comment: I have tried to change the height of the TextView to fill_parent also, but still it dont fill out the whole space?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg2"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#E97305"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="#CCE97305"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg2"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/ticket"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#CCE97305"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```